# Why should bind() be deprecated?

Tags: c++, lambda, std-function, stdbind

Reading the proposal for C++17 about removing some deprecated, old and unused parts of the standard (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4190.htm) i find section D.9 a bit strange:

> D.9 "Binders" [depr.lib.binders]
>
> This defines bind1st()/bind2nd(), which were strictly superseded by bind().
> (In the future, I'll argue that bind() itself has been superseded by lambdas
> and especially generic lambdas, so bind() should be deprecated, but that
> isn't part of this proposal.)

What I don't get is the comment about `bind()` itself being superseded by lambdas.

If I have a class:

```
class A
{
  public:
    void f(int a){}
    void f(int a, int b){}
}
```

And I want to pass a function pointer to `A::f` to some function, `someFunction`, so that this function can call it on an object instantiated from `A`, I declare `someFunction`:

```
void someFunction(const std::function<void(int, int)>&);
```

And call it:

```
A a;
someFunction(std::bind(static_cast<void (A::*)(int, int)> (&A::f),
                       std::ref(a), 
                       std::placeholders::_1,
                       std::placeholders::_2));
```

How do I achieve the same thing using a lambda? Is there really nothing that `bind()` can do, which cannot be done with a lambda?

Comment: C++14 has generic lambdas ( `auto f = [](auto x) { ... }`). Still I like `bind` and I don't think that it should be ever deprecated.

Comment: The section in this paper [Appendix: Why we need bind when we have a generic lambda?](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4171.html#appendix.bind_vs_lambda) makes the case for bind still be useful but it does not seem like a strong case.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour The example in the summary there makes a pretty strong case for me :)

Comment: It is definitely a matter of perspective :-) I guess what I mean is there is no argument of a something that bind can do that a lambda can not. We can of course disagree on usability.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How do you do it?  Very straight forward and less esoteric (*my opinion*) than the bind example with `std::ref` and `placeholders_`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class A
{
public:
   void f(int a) {}
   void f(int a, int b) { std::cout << a + b << '\n';}
};

void someFunction(const std::function<void(int, int)>& f)
{
   f(1, 2);
}

int main()
{
   A a;
   someFunction([&] (int x, int y) { a.f(x, y); });
   return 0;
}
```