# std::bind on member with call operator

Tags: c++, c++11

This might be a silly and stupid thing to do - however I would like to understand what happens here.

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

namespace
{
    struct call
    {
        void operator()() const
        {
            std::cout << "call::operator()" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    struct dummy
    {
        dummy() = default;
        dummy(const dummy&) = delete;

        call member;
    }; 
}
```

So member essentially would work like any other object method, allowing it to be invoked as:

```
dummy d;
d.member()
```

Which would print `call::operator()`.

Now I would like to use bind to do that, the initial implementation looked like this:

```
int main() 
{
    dummy d;

    auto b = std::bind(&dummy::member, &d);
    b();
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles, but nothing is printed. I don't really understand what is happening - the fact that it compiles, but produces no output puzzles me :) surely some magic is going on inside the belly of `std::bind`, but what?

Here is a link to play with the code:
https://ideone.com/P81PND

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, your bind return a member, so `b()` is `d.member`.
You would have to call operator () on that:

```
b()(); // call::operator()
```

As alternative, you may use any of:

```
b = std::bind(&call::operator(), &d.member);
b = [&]() {d.member();};
```

Comment: You are correct! :) We just found that out ourselves. `std::bind` will just return the member, learned something new today - thanks!

Comment: @mortenvp: Lambdas render `std::bind` pretty useless anyway. There has been discussion about deprecating it in a future version of C++. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33835922/why-should-bind-be-deprecated

Comment: @Jarod42, and surprisingly, `std::cref` - see below.

Answer (score 0):

You can also call through a `std::reference_wrapper`. No need for `bind` at all.

```
int main() 
{
    dummy d;

    auto b= std::cref(d.member);  // create reference wrapper
    b();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or regular reference.